# Python argparse - make arguments required or optional based on another argument

Tags: python, argparse

How can a program accept/validate a set of parameters, depending on a previous parameter/option?

e.g:

```
params:
        <action1> -p <path>  -name <name> -t <type>
        <action2> -v <value> -name <name>
        <action3> -p <path> -t <type>
        <action4> -m <mode1 | mode2>
        --verbose
        --test
        --..
```

So if one of the `actionX` parameters is used (only one can be used), additional parameters might be required.
For instance for `action2` the `-v` and `-name` are required.

**valid input:**

```
python myparser.py action2 -v 11 -name something --test --verbose
python myparser.py action4 -m mode1 
python myparser.py --test
```

**invalid input:**

```
python myparser.py action2 -v 11 
python myparser.py action4 -n name1
```

Can the `argparse` validate this or is it better to add all of them as *optional* and validate them later on?

Comment: I think you may want to give a look to [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Simple example for your case

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", action="store_true")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_action2 = subparsers.add_parser("action2")
parser_action2.add_argument("-v", required=True)
parser_action2.add_argument("-name", type=str, required=True)

parser_action4 = subparsers.add_parser("action4")
parser_action4.add_argument("-m", type=str, required=True)
```

valid case

```py
parser.parse_args(["action2", "-v", "11", "-name", "something"])
parser.parse_args(["action4", "-m", "mode1"])
parser.parse_args(["--test"])

# Namespace(v='11', name='something')
# Namespace(m='mode1')
# Namespace(test=True)
```

Invalid case

```py
parser.parse_args(["action2", "-v", "11"])
# action2: error: the following arguments are required: -name

parser.parse_args(["action4", "-n", "name1"])
# action4: error: the following arguments are required: -m
```

EDIT: And in case you want to use shared argument which is required in one and optional in others, it is better to make them optional and validate them later as you said.

Comment: Thanks, `subparsers` is what I need! :)